# Use of 'period' at the end of sentence

Tags: word-usage, quotes, dialogue

I have observed this in some quotes or dialogues that people say 'period.' at the end of their sentence/quote.

I wanted to ask why and when is it used

Comment: I don't know where you're from, but Americans call a full stop a period.  Saying it out loud emphasises the sentence and implies 'That's all there is to say about it.'

Comment: Ohh thanks. By the way, I'm from India. Thanks for your help again

Comment: This is explained in [dictionary definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/period): "**5 a (2)**: —used interjectionally to emphasize the finality of the preceding statement // I don't remember — *period*."

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for help :)